# What does "this[0]" mean in C#?

Tags: c#

I was going through some library code and saw a method like:

```
public CollapsingRecordNodeItemList List
{
    get { return this[0] as CollapsingRecordNodeItemList; }
}
```

The class that contains this method is not a list or something iterable, so what exactly does `this[0]` mean?

Comment: the class has an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx)

Comment: Does the class override the index operator []?

Comment: @Nick I just saw that one of the parent classes has a line like `public GoObject this[string name] { get; set; }` maybe its related to this ?

Comment: There'll be another one which is indexed on integers.

Comment: @Cemre see if there is a `this[int index]` or `this[long index]` or something like that... you can't pass an integer (`0`) in as `string name`.

Comment: @Cemre, thats just another indexer. The parent class is indexed with the `string` type.

Comment: Marc is correct.. it is the same idea - it is an indexer but it is not the one your line is referring..

Comment: Yeah as you said there was another one: `public virtual GoObject this[int index] { get; set; }`. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Just an additional piece of information that might help future readers. Indexers were first introduced in the abstract class Collectionbase. This feature was later also made a part of List<T>.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Look for an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx) in the class.

C# lets you define indexers to allow this sort of access.

Here is an example from the official guide for "SampleCollection".

```
public T this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            // This indexer is very simple, and just returns or sets 
            // the corresponding element from the internal array. 
            return arr[i];
        }
        set
        {
            arr[i] = value;
        }
    }
```

Here is the definition from [the official language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029):

> An **indexer** is a member that enables objects to be indexed in the same way as an array. An indexer is declared like a property except that the name of the member is this followed by a parameter list written between the delimiters [ and ]. The parameters are available in the accessor(s) of the indexer. Similar to properties, indexers can be read-write, read-only, and write-only, and the accessor(s) of an indexer can be virtual.

One can find the full and complete definition in section **10.9 Indexers** of the specification.

Comment: I discovered a property in one of the parent classes but the index is `string` instead of `int` : `public GoObject this[string name] { get; set; }` . I guess there is another one somewhere else.

Comment: @Cemre The language specification states that (section 1.6.7.3) "Indexers can be overloaded, meaning that a class can declare multiple indexers as long as the number or types of their parameters differ." :) This might be the case here

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Just found the other one which was: `public virtual GoObject this[int index] { get; set; }` :)

Answer (score 10):

It means that the declaring type (or a base-class of that) has an "indexer" which presumably takes an `int` (or similar) and returns... something (perhaps `object` ?). The code calls the indexer's `get` accessor, passing `0` as the index - and then treats the returned value as a `CollapsingRecordNodeItemList` (or `null` the returned value isn't compatible with that).

For example:

```
public object this[int index] {
    get { return someOtherList[index]; }
}
```

Easiest thing to do is the step into it, though. That will tell you **exactly** where it is going.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the class itself inherits from some form if `IList`/`IList<T>`, it's just returning (and casting) the first element in the collection.

```
public class BarCollection : System.Collections.CollectionBase
{
    public Bar FirstItem
    {
        get { return this[0] as Bar; }
    }

    #region Coming From CollectionBase
    public Object this[ int index ]  {
        get { return this.InnerList[index]; }
        set { this.InnerList[index] = value; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: `IEnumerable` does not define an indexer, I suspect you mean `IList<T>`.

Comment: Indeed, still waking up and working on coffee. ;-) Good catch, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It means to invoke the `item` property's `get` method on this class. It's called the class's [Indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx)

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take parameters.