# Is this[0] safe in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, language-lawyer, this-pointer

[This earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650223/what-does-this0-mean-in-c) asks what `this[0]` means in C#.  In C++, `this[0]` means "the zeroth element of the array pointed at by `this`."

Is it guaranteed to not cause undefined behavior in C++ to refer to the receiver object this way?  I'm not advocating for using this syntax, and am mostly curious whether the spec guarantees this will always work.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's well-defined, going along the lines of how `&obj + 1` is.

Comment: I've used it sometimes with gdb: say you did `p complex-expression-that-yields-pointer`, but you wanted to see the contents of the object, not the pointer, so press up, type `[0]` and done. No need to scroll to the beginning of the expression and add parenthesis (probably).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For any valid object pointer `p`, `p[0]` is equivalent to `*p`. So `this[0]` is equivalent to `*this`. There's nothing more to it. Just like you can dereference any valid pointer using `[0]`, you can dereference `this` with it.

In other words, it is just a "tricky" way to write `*this`. It can be used to obfuscate code. It can probably be used in some specific circumstances for useful purposes as well, since any standalone object can be thought of as an array of size 1. (From C++03, Additive operators: "For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type.")

P.S. As Johannes noted in the comments, by using C++11 features it is possible to come up with a context in which `this` is a pointer to an incomplete type. In that case `this[0]` expression becomes invalid, while `*this` expression remains valid.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are aware of it, but the answer states it different. The following is illformed, and replacing `this[0]` by `*this` makes it wellformed. `struct A { auto f () -> decltype (this [0]); };`.

Comment: Right, what Johannes said, `p[0]` doesn't work when `p` is a pointer to an incomplete type. To add to that, the type could be incomplete because it isn't yet completed, as in Johannes's example, but it could also be because the type cannot be completed (such as `T(*)[]`). It (of course) also doesn't work for non-object pointer types.

Answer (score 11):

`this[0]` is the same as `*(this + 0)`, so indeed this is fine (albeit a bit weird).

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic, but does the ISO spec guarantee this?  I'm well aware of this identity, but the spec often makes a distinction between objects and arrays.

Comment: @templatetypedef, `&obj + 1` is valid despite whether `obj` is an array or a single object. I would assume the same applies here.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Actually, the `[]` does not operate on arrays, only on pointers. The array decays into a pointer and the `[]` works with the pointer and the index. So, yes, it is guaranteed.

Comment: @templatetypedef: From C++03, Additive operators: "For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type."

Answer (score 3):

Yep, it's the same thing as `*this`

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK basically `this[0]` is exactly the same as `*this`, as `this` is just a normal pointer.
So yes it is safe to use.

`array[1]` would be the same as `*(array + 1)` (when `array` is valid) fyi...

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent (by definition) to `*(this + 0)`, which is the same as `*this`.  It is safe and well-defined, but weird.

Answer (score -2):

`this[0]` is same as `*(this + sizeof(this)*0)` so it's quite safe

Added small test as answer to comment

```
struct A
{
    void * _a;
    int _b;

    A * getThis(int index)
    {
        return &(this[index]);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    A mas[100];

    std::cout << ((long long) mas[0].getThis(50) == (long long) &(mas[50])) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While your answer is *technically* correct. The `sizeof(this)` is superfluous and implies that `this[1]` is the same as `*(this + sizeof(this)*1)`.  Or that `this[N]` is generally equivalent to `*(this + sizeof(this)*N)`.  This is, of course, false.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley see small test that, I think, prove my point

Comment: I don't know what point you are trying to prove with your test.  Did you understand my comment?  My point is that `this[N]` is *not* equivalent to `*(this + sizeof(this)*N)`, but your original answer, in my opinion, implies that they are equivalent.  The `sizeof(this)` is completely pointless, and only happens to work out because it is being multiplied by 0.  But for any other value of `N` besides 0, it does not work.  So why is it in your formula?

Comment: pointer+integer addition is already scaled by the size of the pointed-to object. `this[0]` happens to be the same as `*(this + sizeof(this)*0)`, but `this[N]` is *not* the same as `*(this + sizeof(this) * N)`'; rather, it's equivalent to `*(this + N)` (which is the object `N * sizeof *this` bytes, or more simply `N` *elements*, past the location pointed to by `this`). In any case, `sizeof(this)` is irrelevant; that gives you the size of the pointer, not the size of the pointed-to object.